# Sharepoint 2010 I need to store List of objects into database

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-api

I need to store few objects (Not simple Type) to sharepoint and access them from all sites. My first try was to save with SPPersistedObject but lists cannot be saved:

```
he platform does not know how to deserialize an object of type DataItems.SearchResultItem. The platform can deserialize primitive types such as strings, integers, and GUIDs; other SPPersistedObjects or SPAutoserializingObjects; or collections of any of the above. Consider redesigning your objects to store values in one of these supported formats, or contact your software vendor for support.
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to store SPPersistedObject and serialize objects to xml string.

Answer (score 1):

What are you actually trying to save? Can it be simplified into a SharePoint list with different columns that represent the whole of what you are trying to save?

Comment: Some cache data Title and Url. (have to be stored in db)! Is i really have to create list?